# I have a problem when creating a CSV file in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV files and I want to combine them. 
but the result he also wrote a number on the new file as below:

```
0,98,32,76,...
1,63,84,95,...
2,12,34,65,...
```

how to have no number in my combined file
what I want without the initial number like below:

```
98,32,76,...
63,84,95,...
12,34,65,...
```

my code is now like this :

```
import pandas as pd
vector = pd.read_csv('data/vector_train.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
label = pd.read_csv('data/label_train.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")   
vector['label'] = label['label']
export_csv = vector.to_csv (r'data/vector_label.csv')
```

Comment: add option `index_col=[0]` to `read_csv`.

Comment: its work, thank you very much for you guys

Comment: @QuangHoang that suggestion will cause the first column of the csv file to be the index of the dataframe which will change the logic and behavior of the rest of the code. It's better to explicitly tell `to_csv` to not dump the index as shown in my answer

Answer (score 1):

By default `to_csv` dumps the index column. To remediate this just pass `index=False` to `to_csv`:

```
vector.to_csv (r'data/vector_label.csv', index=False)
```

On a side note, in this case `to_csv` does not return anything so assigning its call to `export_df` is not useful.